# Extract few matching strings from matching lines in file using sed

Tags: regex, shell, sed

I have a file with strings similar to this:

```
abcd u'current_count': u'2', u'total_count': u'3', u'order_id': u'90'
```

I have to find current_count and total_count for each line of file. I am trying below command but its not working. Please help.

```
grep current_count file | sed "s/.*\('current_count': u'\d+'\).*/\1/"
```

It is outputting the whole line but I want something like this:

```
'current_count': u'3', 'total_count': u'3'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's printing the whole line because the pattern in the `s` command doesn't match, so no substitution happens.

`sed` regexes don't support `\d` for digits, or `x+` for `xx*`.  GNU sed has a `-r` option to enable extended-regex support so `+` will be a meta-character, but `\d` still doesn't work.  GNU sed also allows `\+` as a meta-character in basic regex mode, but that's not POSIX standard.

So anyway, this will work:

```
echo -e "foo\nabcd u'current_count': u'2', u'total_count': u'3', u'order_id': u'90'" |
sed -nr "s/.*('current_count': u'[0-9]+').*/\1/p"
# output:  'current_count': u'2'
```

Notice that I skip the grep by using `sed -n s///p`.  I could also have used `/current_count/` as an address:

```
sed  -r -e '/current_count/!d' -e "s/.*('current_count': u'[0-9]+').*/\1/"
```

Or with just grep printing only the matching part of the pattern, instead of the whole line:

```
grep -E -o "'current_count': u'[[:digit:]]+'
```

(or egrep instead of grep -E).  I forget if `grep -o` is POSIX-required behaviour.

Comment: Thanks. This works but why you used `p` at the end of the sed command.

Comment: @Anuj: `sed -n` doesn't print out lines by default.  `s///p` prints the pattern space only if a successful substitution was made.  So it's using the `s/pattern/` to filter the lines as well, doing the job that `grep` was doing before, or that `/current_count/!d` (delete non-matching lines) was doing.  This is all in the `sed` man page.

Answer (score 0):

For me this looks like some sort of serialized Python data. Basically I would try to find out the origin of that data and parse it properly.

However, while being hackish, `sed` can also being used here:

```
sed "s/.*current_count': [a-z]'\([0-9]\+\).*/\1/" input.txt
sed "s/.*total_count': [a-z]'\([0-9]\+\).*/\1/" input.txt
```

Comment: Yes, it's a Python API request data. I just gave the part of line for example. And I tried the same string as mentioned in your answer but it does not work. It looks like this should work but not working for me.